# Creating Table Schema on Spark DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I would like to create table structure just like in other sql engines on Spark DataBricks platform on cloud. I have couple of question related to this,

1. How to create column with default value ? Example - Should store current date while inserting records
2. Partition table based on year and month column

Help appreciated !!

Answer (score 2):

To create a `createdDate` column for your dataframe,

```
df.withColumn("createdDate",lit(current_date()).show(5)

+---+-----------+
|id |createdDate|
+---+-----------+
|0  |2019-11-29 |
|1  |2019-11-29 |
|2  |2019-11-29 |
|3  |2019-11-29 |
|4  |2019-11-29 |
+---+-----------+
```

To store a dataframe by partitioning using `save` function,

```
#Default format will be parquet
df.write.partitionBy("year","month").save("<path>/df.parquet")
```

To store a dataframe by partitioning using `saveAsTable` function,

```
#Default format will be parquet
df.write.partitionBy("year","month").saveAsTable("<tablename>")
```

Sample folder structure after partitioning based on year and month,

```
├── df.parquet
│   ├── _SUCCESS
│   └── year=2019
│       └── month=11
│           └── part-00000-ba8da035-aff2-44bc-9921-ed8a1d6e2cb3.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Answer (score 0):

Default Values for tables like we know them from standard SQL do not exist in spark/databricks.
You have to do that in your ETL Process like Aravind Palani showed above.

Anyways, you can do a normal create table in spark-sql and you can cover partitioning there.

example:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    Name string,
    Firstname string,
    Age int
)
PARTITIONED BY (Age, Firstname)
```

Is this what you were looking for?